# Can somebody please help me identify this gearbox?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, gears, mechanisms

I want to identify whether this is a bevel gearbox/worm gearbox or a standard gearbox from an automobile. This is a tractor PTO driven winch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The right-angle gearbox in the photo is most likely a bevel gear. Any worm gears I have seen would have the drive shaft tangential to the output shaft gear.

[image]

*Figure 1. The axles of a spur gear can be on the same plane as in the OP's photo. Image source: [Roboshop](https://www.robotshop.com/eu/en/servocity-21-bevel-gear-set-1-4-bore-pinion-14-bore-spur.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwio6XBhCMARIsAC0u9aEppIDZ92UyfnjemNTvDqsGtnxc8rdwi2aD1IsW605v_VC4oJqQdzQaAsodEALw_wcB).*

[image]

*Figure 2. A worm gear's shafts are not on the same plane. Image source: [Direct Industry](https://www.directindustry.com/prod/hydromec/product-38532-464914.html).*